# css file not considered when more than one route used with express, ejs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

If I use `app.get("/compose")` or `app.get("/dynamic")`- that is - single route, my `CSS` file is taken into effect and `h1`, `p` are styled accordingly, but if I use `app.get("/posts/dynamic")` - that is - double route, my `CSS` file is not taken into consideration, although headers and footers are working fine

My `app.js` file:

```
   const express = require("express");
   const app = express();

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/compose", function(req, res) {
res.render("compose");
});

app.get("/posts/dynamic", function(req, res) {
res.render("dynamic");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("started running on port 3000");
});
```

My `dynamic.ejs` file:

```
<%- include("header"); -%>

<h1> Test </h1>
<p> Test Paragrapgh Content <p>

<%- include("footer"); -%>
```

My `contact.ejs` file:

```
<%- include("header"); -%>

<h1> Contact Us </h1>
<p> Contact Us Content </p>

<%- include("footer"); -%>
```

Is my `express.static();` going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here, what I tried and Worked.

1. Set a `view Engine` for `EJS`

   ```
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   ```
2. then add

   ```
   app.use(express.static('public'));
   ```

and assuming your folder structure is :

```
project root 
     ├── server.js
     ├── package.json 
     └── public   
       ├── css  
         └── style.css
```

and in your `header.ejs` add this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

and your `dynamic.ejs` file is

```
<%- include('./header.ejs'); %>

<h1> Test </h1>
<p> Test Paragrapgh Content <p>

<%- include('./footer.ejs'); %>
```

**Addition**

It is also possible to define multiple folders at the same time

```
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use(express.static('images'));
```